# Match one of several bytes in nom

Tags: macros, rust, nom

I am using [nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom) to parse some binary 65c816 assembly data. Part of my parser structure splits opcodes into their separate forms and then grabs their parameters if they have any. An example parser currently looks like this:

```
named!(absolute_long<Instruction>, 
    do_parse!(op: bits!(alt!(
        opcode!(0x0F) | opcode!(0x22) | opcode!(0x2F) | opcode!(0x4F) | 
        opcode!(0x5C) | opcode!(0x6F) | opcode!(0x8F) | opcode!(0xAF) | 
        opcode!(0xCF) | opcode!(0xEF)))
>> param: le_u24
>> (Instruction::AbsoluteLong(op, param))));
```

Where `opcode!` is a macro I made that does the following:

```
macro_rules! opcode(
    ($i:expr, $op:expr) => (
        tag_bits!($i, u8, 8, $op);
    );
    ($i:expr, $f:expr) => (
        opcode!($i, call!($f));
    );
);
```

I would instead like to have code like the following but am unable to figure out how I'd make a macro or function to do it:

```
named!(absolute_long<Instruction>, 
    do_parse!(op: opcodes!(
        0x0F, 0x22, 0x2F, 0x4F, 0x5C, 0x6F, 0x8F, 0xAF, 
        0xCF, 0xEF)
    >> param: le_u24
    >> (Instruction::AbsoluteLong(op, parm)));
```

The closest I got was making this macro, but it almost immediately runs into recursion limits and it seems really sub-optimal in general:

```
macro_rules! opcodes(
    ($i:expr, $op:expr) => {
        opcode!($i, $op)
    };

    ($i:expr, $op:expr, $($more:expr), *) => (
        bits!($i, alt!(opcode!($op) | opcodes!($($more),*)))
    );
);
```

Is there any way I can implement something like this or am I better off just using `tag_bits`? I feel like I should be able to use `one_of`, but I am unable to get it to work with bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`one_of!(..)`](http://rust.unhandledexpression.com/nom/macro.one_of.html) like [so](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=406c02cf7cabed0f7a9fa6fa8ff12e25&version=stable):

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;
use nom::*;

// Your type might look a different, I infered what I could:
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Instruction {
    AbsoluteLong(u8, u32)
}

named!(absolute_long<Instruction>, do_parse!(
       op: one_of!([0x0F, 0x22, 0x2F, 0x4F, 0x5C, 0x6F, 0x8F, 0xAF, 0xCF, 0xEF].as_ref())
    >> param: le_u24
    >> (Instruction::AbsoluteLong(op as u8, param))
));

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", absolute_long(&[0x0F, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01]));
}
```

`one_of!` must be given a slice to work with. We can get one by casting an array to it with [`.as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html#tymethod.as_ref).

Comment: Thank you! I tried working with `one_of!` for quite some time, but since I'm new to Rust I wasn't aware of `.as_ref()` or how to interpret the errors relating to slices. Doing it like that gets rid of my macros and makes all these parsers look a lot cleaner.

Comment: Arrays and slice syntax can be a bit tricky. You are welcome =)